# Not able to see subtitles in video converted using zencoder

Tags: php, brightcove, zencoder

For converting some video to MP4 i am using zencoder services, everything works fine. But now i want to add subtitles to the processed video, just like ffmpeg does

```
ffmpeg -i src-video.mp4 -vf subtitles=subs.srt processed-video.mp4
```

i followed https://app.zencoder.com/docs/api/encoding/captions but i am still not able to add subtitles using zencoder, i am sending POST request to

```
https://app.zencoder.com/api/v2/jobs
```

with payload

```
{
  "input": "s3+us-west-2://bucket/src-video.mp4",
  "outputs": [
    {
      "url": "s3+us-west-2://bucket/processed-video.mp4",
      "credentials": "zencoder_s3",
      "caption_url": "s3+us-west-2://bucket/subs.scc"
    }
  ]
}
```

S3 bucket is accessible to zencoder and after video processing the output does not contains the subtitle.

Comment: i converted my srt file to scc using https://gotranscript.com/subtitle-converter

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer after crawling many web pages,

actually only quick-time player can play scc type of closed caption but only when converted video is in m4v format.